# ClassCastException on MyFirstApp

Tags: android

For the first time I'm going over the tutorial on how to create an app on Android using the following URL: [MyFirstApp](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

When I ran it, I got a ClassCastException on my stacktrace through LogCat which looks like this:

```
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     ... 11 more
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:34)
03-02 13:18:49.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     ... 14 more
```

This is referencing the method sendMessage(View view) in Class MainActivity.  Originally it looked like this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, this caused the same ClassCastException problem.  In my research I stumbled on this article:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32941

which states I should change the EditText object with a TextView object. I did that.  So now my method looks like this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    TextView tView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = tView.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

That compiled fine.  But I'm still getting that same ClassCastException as noted in the stacktrace log.  I don't know how to fix this.  Please advise.

Alan

Comment: also see [Building a Simple User Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)  training section before [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `res/layout/activity_main.xml` (it's the default layout file, it can be named differently in your project), what's the type of `edit_message`?

It should be the same one in your cast `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);`.